# How to resolve the magento theme error

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

> Blockquoteget();
>   //$themeCfg->getField
>   class Sns_Sport_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {

```
public $data;
public function __construct(){
    $this->defaults = array();
    $this->data = $this->get();
}
public function get($attributes=array()) {
    //Varien_Profiler::start('SNS Sport');
    $this->data                     = $this->defaults;

    $config = array();

    foreach(Mage::getStoreConfig("sns_sport_cfg") as $k => $group){
        $groupName = $k;
        foreach($group as $key => $value){
            $config[$groupName.'_'.$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    foreach(Mage::getStoreConfig("sns_sport_sticky") as $k => $group){
        $groupName = $k;
        foreach($group as $key => $value){
            $config[$groupName.'_'.$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    if (is_array($config))              $this->data= array_merge($this->data, $config);
    if (!is_array($attributes))         $attributes = array($attributes);

    $cookies = Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get();

    $tplName = Mage::getSingleton("core/design_package")->getPackageName() . '_' . Mage::getSingleton("core/design_package")->getTheme("frontend") . '_';

    if(!is_null(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('sns_clearcookie'))){
        foreach($cookies as $key => $value) {
            if(preg_match("/$tplName/", $key)){
                Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->delete($key, Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->getPath());
            }
        }
    } else {
        if($this->data['advance_showCpanel'] == 1) {
            foreach($cookies as $key => $value) {
                $key = preg_replace("/$tplName/", '', $key);
                if($key == 'general_bodyBgImage'){
                    $this->data['general_bodyBgImage2'] = '';
                }
                if(isset($this->data[$key])) {
                    $this->data[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(!is_null(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('color_skin'))) {
        $this->data['advance_themeColor'] = "#" . Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('color_skin');
        Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->set($tplName.'advance_themeColor', $this->data['advance_themeColor']);
    }
    //Varien_Profiler::stop('SNS Sport');

    return array_merge($this->data, $attributes);;
}
public function getField($field) {
    $this->data= $this->get();
    if(isset($this->data[$field])) {
        return $this->data[$field];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public function getImgRate() {
    return 0.8;
}
public function getImgSize($size) {
    $size = strtoupper($size);

    $imgRate = $this->getImgRate();
    $imgS_w = 80; // small img
    $imgM_w = 90; // detail thumb img
    $imgL_w = 180; // grid product img
    $imgXL_w = 500; // detail big img
    $imgXXL_w = 600;

    if($size == 'S') return array($imgS_w, $imgS_w / $imgRate);
    if($size == 'M') return array($imgM_w, $imgM_w / $imgRate);
    if($size == 'L') return array($imgL_w, $imgL_w / $imgRate);
    if($size == 'XL') return array($imgXL_w, $imgXL_w / $imgRate);
    if($size == 'XXL') return array($imgXXL_w, $imgXXL_w / $imgRate);
    return;
    //  $imgSize = Mage::helper('sport/data')->getImgSize(S);
    //  $imgSize[0], $imgSize[1]
}

public function getThemeCSS($attributes=array()) {
    $themeCssName = 'theme-' . str_replace("#", "", $this->getField('advance_themeColor')) . str_replace("#", "", $this->getField('advance_themeColor2'));
    return 'css/'.$themeCssName.'.css';
}
public function checkBrowser () {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/chrome/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'Chrome';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/safari/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'Safari';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/opera/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'OP';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/msie/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'IE';
}
public function getBrowser () {
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/chrome/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'chrome';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/safari/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'safari';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/opera/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) return 'op';
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/msie/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        preg_match('/MSIE (.*?);/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $reg); //Zend_Debug::dump($reg); die();
        if(!isset($reg[1])) {
            return 'ie';
        } else {
            return 'ie' . ' ie' . floatval($reg[1]);
        }
    }
}

public function getCfg($optionString) {
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('sns_sport_cfg/' . $optionString);
}
public function delCacheCss ($directory, $minute) {
    if ($directory != '.') {
        $directory = rtrim($directory, '/') . '/';
    }
    if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                if(preg_match("/^theme-/i", $file) && preg_match("/css$/i", $file)) {
                    $filePath = $directory.$file;
                    $time_elapsed = (time() - filemtime($filePath)) / 60;
                    if($time_elapsed > $minute){
                        unlink($filePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
public function cacheRefresh ($types = NULL) {
    $types = array('config', 'layout', 'block_html', 'translate', 'collections', 'eav', 'config_api', 'config_api2');
    foreach ($types as $type) {
        $tags = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_cache_refresh_type', array('type' => $type));
    }
}
public function compileLess () {

    $skin_path = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir();
    $skinDefaultPath = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinBaseDir(array('_theme' => 'default'));

    $themeColor = $this->getField('advance_themeColor');
    $themeColor2 = $this->getField('advance_themeColor2');

    $themeCssName = 'theme-' . str_replace("#", "", $themeColor) . str_replace("#", "", $themeColor2);
    $themeCssPath = $skin_path.'/css/'.$themeCssName.'.css';


    $variables = (array(
        "color1" => $themeColor,
        "color2" => $themeColor2
    ));
    $format = ($this->getField('advance_lessCompress')) ? 'compressed' : '';

    if($this->getField('advance_showCpanel')) {
    //  $this->delCacheCss($skin_path.'/css/', 10);
    }
    $lessPath = $skin_path . '/less/theme.less';
    if(!file_exists($lessPath)) {
        $lessPath = $skinDefaultPath . '/less/theme.less';
        $themeCssPath = $skinDefaultPath.'/css/'.$themeCssName.'.css';
    }
    if($this->getField('advance_lessEnabled') || !file_exists($themeCssPath)) {
        $this->_compileLess($lessPath, $themeCssPath, $variables, $format);
    }
}
public function _compileLess ($lessPath, $themeCssPath, $variables, $format) {
    $less = new lessc;
    $less->setVariables($variables);
    if($format) $less->setFormatter($format);
    $less->compileFile($lessPath, $themeCssPath);
}
public function getAttributeAdminLabel($attributeCode, $item){
    ///trunk/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Config.php
    $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getEntityType('catalog_product');
    //$entityTypeId = $entityType->getEntityTypeId();
    $attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode($entityType, $attributeCode);
    $_collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
                      ->setAttributeFilter($attributeModel->getId())
                    ->setStoreFilter(0)
                    ->load();

    foreach( $_collection->toOptionArray() as $_cur_option ) {
        if ($_cur_option['value'] == $item->getValue()){ return $_cur_option['label']; }
    }
    return $item->getLabel();
}
public function getImgHtml($_content, $_width, $_height){
    preg_match_all("/\<img[^\>]*>/", $_content, $img);

    if(!preg_match("/\{{media [^\>]*}}/", $img[0][0], $mediaImgUrl) && $img[0][0] != '') {
        return $img[0][0];
    }

    if($img[0][0]){
        preg_match("/\{{media [^\>]*}}/", $img[0][0], $mediaImgUrl);
        $mediaImgUrl = preg_replace(array('/{{media url=/', '/}}/', '/"/', '/\'/'), array('', '', '', ''), $mediaImgUrl[0]);

        $imgName = explode("/", $mediaImgUrl);

        $_imgDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media');
        $_imgUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media');


        for($i = 0; $i < count($imgName) - 1; $i++){
            $_imgDir .= DS . $imgName[$i];
            $_imgUrl .= $imgName[$i] . '/';
        }
        $_imgDir .= DS;
        $_imgName = $imgName[count($imgName) - 1];

    } else {
        $_imgDir = Mage::getBaseDir('skin') . DS . 'frontend' . DS . 'default' . DS . 'default' . DS . 'images' . DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product' . DS . 'placeholder' . DS;
        $_imgName = 'image.jpg';
    }

    $_cacheDir = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'cache' . DS . 'blog' . DS;
    $_cacheUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl('media') . 'cache' . '/blog/';

    if (file_exists($_cacheDir . $_imgName)) {
        return '<img src="'.$_cacheUrl . $_imgName.'" alt="" />';
    } elseif (file_exists($_imgDir . $_imgName)) {
        if (!is_dir($_cacheDir)) {
            mkdir($_cacheDir);
        }
        $_image = new Varien_Image($_imgDir . $_imgName);
        $_image->constrainOnly(true);
        $_image->keepAspectRatio(false);
        $_image->keepFrame(true);
        $_image->keepTransparency(true);
        $_image->backgroundColor(array(255,255,255));
        $_image->resize($_width, $_height);
        $_image->save($_cacheDir . $_imgName);

        return '<img src="'.$_cacheUrl . $_imgName.'" alt="" />';
    }
}
public function getImgUrl($_content){
    preg_match_all("/\<img[^\>]*>/", $_content, $img);

    if($img[0] && is_array($img[0])) {
        $imgTag = Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter($img[0][0]);
        $attrs = explode(" ", $imgTag);
        foreach($attrs as $attr) {
            if(preg_match('/^src="/i', $attr)) {
                $attrSrc = $attr;
            }
        }
        return $attrSrc;
    } else {
        return Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor()->filter('src="{{media url="wysiwyg/sport/blog/no-image.jpg"}}"');
    }
}
```

}

> Blockquote

[image]
I wanted to change the theme of the magento. i was using default rwd theme before.Now decided to switch to sns-sports theme and uploaded all theme files to FTP. my admin panel of sns_sport is working fine but when i put the theme live i get this fatal error.Can anyone please solve the error..

[image]

Comment: Try to clear Magento cache. Do you have disable cache before installing theme ?

Comment: Yes i had disabled cache before installing the theme..

Answer (score 0):

I guss,*error handling is enable at live systrem*,so you **see the error at live**

But may be *`in local system, error handing is not enable`* that you **does not see the error**.

The screenshot indicated,there are **an issue** at a file *`Data.php`* which located at *`app/code/local/Sns/Sport/Helper/`*.

In this file at line 180 , a constant variable ***STRAIGHT_JOIN*** which is *`not defined and for resolve this which you need to be defined`*

> ```
> <?php 
> class Sns_Sport_Helper_Data  extends ......{
> /* add this */
>  const STRAIGHT_JOIN='SOME_THING_VALUE';
> .....
>  }
> ```

Comment: it did not work..:( its showing the same error again

Comment: .After my change,you got another issue.I have see that you was changed question content That  make confusion.For better to Carry the old issue screen shot with  current content.Thus user can understand.

Comment: Those two images are same and sorry for inconvience.

Comment: please share code?

Comment: I have included the code in the question..

Comment: please share code at pestbin

Comment: http://pastebin.com/aHPRdH4m

Comment: The  Actuall Problem is the theme is working fine in Local host. But its not working live..I have uploaded all the files properly.

Answer (score 0):

See http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Go to your /var/www/magento/app/code/local/Sns/Sport/Helper/Data.php file to see how the lessphp class is included...

This theme require some files in addition.

See SNS Sport documentation to help you for add required files

Comment: http://paste.bradleygill.com/index.php?paste_id=1328923

Comment: Fatal Error:
====================
parse error: failed at `foreach(Mage::getStoreConfig("sns_sport_cfg") as $k => $group){` line: 17